# How to make grid operations work with custom property in EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, gridview

In a `ASP.NET MVC 5` web site I have a GridView using the devexpress component binding using the LINQ method.

EF generated a partial class to map a table that i use to display in that gridview.
In this partial class generated by the EF i have a `ID_Status` property wich has a corresponding description in other table. I made another partial class to deal with this custom Property and it works ok, except when i try to make a 'Sort' operation clicking on the header of this column.

The partial class generated by the EF.

```
  [Table("Test")]
  public partial class Test
  {
    [Key]
    public long ID_Test { get; set; }
    public long ID_TestStatus { get; set; }
    //other properties
  }
```

My Custom partial class:

```
public partial class Test
{
    private static readonly TestRepository _testRepository;

    static TestRepository()
    {
        _testRepository= new TestRepository();
    }

    public string StatusDescription
    {
        get { return _testRepository.GetStatusDescriptionById(ID_TestStatus); }
    }
}
```

When i try to `Sort` using another column it works fine, but when i try to `Sort` using the custom property Column all the grid cell values gets empty, without any value.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This sorting is probably handled in the Dev Express component. You will need to track the sort call down to where it's comparing entities, and then how that component is being returned to update the grid (postback? or ajax?) I've done this with GridMVC but couldn't tell you where to start from your question. I suggest you debug more and see if you can figure out the 'guts' of the sort function. As the Model and Repository code you've shown give no insight.

Comment: I'd guess that your component tries to apply a filter to that property in LINQ to Entities, and as far as the Entity/RDB mapping is concerned, that property doesn't exist.

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, the problem of the Devexpress components is that some stuff are@ a blackbox

Comment: @ggui in that case, give GridMVC a try. http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very good idea to have data access code inside an entity. One reason is that it makes it very hard to write unit test. Another reason is that it is very likely to give rise to the n + 1 anti pattern. In your case, it does: one (1) query to get the `Test`s, then each `Test` (n) sends a separate query to the database to get its `StatusDescription`.

The way you implemented it also raises some eyebrows, because

1. `_testRepository` is static, which meas there is probable some context instance living for the entire lifecycle of the application - unless `GetStatusDescriptionById` creates a new context for each call, but that wouldn't be a good idea either.
2. The `GetStatusDescriptionById` call is made each time the property is accessed. In a web application this may not be a big problem because the objects are newly created each time they are requested anyway, but in other environments this could be highly inefficient.

A better approach would be to fetch the `Tests`s with their `Status` included:

```
context.Tests.Include(t => t.TestStatus)
```

and have an unmapped property like

```
public string StatusDescription
{
    get { return TestStatus== null ? string.Empty : TestStatus.Description; }
}
```

better still (in my opinion) would be not to show `Test` objects directly, but `TestDto` objects like

```
public class TestDto
{
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    //other properties that match Test's properties
}
```

and use a tool like AutoMapper to map a collection of `Test`s to `TestDto`s. If `Test` has a property `Status` and `TestStatus` has a property `Description`, AutoMapper will be able to flatten that into `StatusDescription` automatically.

Both this `StatusDescription` property and the Dto appraoch set the state of a `Test(Dto)` object once. I don't think any grid component can mess with that.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, and thans for the message, you clear my ideas with this answer. The only doubt i do is, where i need to fetch the Test with its Status? On the `GetStatusDescriptionById` method? And wheres the TestStatus class comes from?

Comment: Well, as it happens, I'm genuinely against an extra repository layer on top of the repository (DbSet) that comes with EF, so I may be the wring person to ask. But you could have a repository method for it with a parameterized `Include`. I assumed you had a TestStatus class in you model because there is a `ID_TestStatus` property. So, seemingly, `Test` could also have a `TestStatus` navigation property.